# What does SQL Server return to C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlclient

We can easily work with SQL Server databases with the help of `System.Data.SqlClient` library in C#.

We can return values from stored procedures or we can write sql commands by hardcoding them in C# code.

Then we pass the result to a `SqlDataReader` to read the values.

But I am really wondering what SQL Server returns to C#.

C# makes the call to SQL Server and SQL Server gives something (XML, JSON or whatever it is) to C# on return.

What is this thing really? And how can we get only this thing if we want to read it through manually ourselves?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe SQL Server at least *used* to use [TDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabular_Data_Stream) for its data transfer. I don't know whether it still does - and using it directly would make your code very brittle in the face of changes within SQL Server. The whole point of having client libraries is to isolate you from the intricacies of the protocol.

What *benefit* are you trying to derive from reading through this manually, over (say) using [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx), which is about as low-level as most applications will ever need?

Comment: thanks. actually I wouldn't quit using those built-in libraries. I just wanted to know what it is returning on the first base in order to understand better what T-SQL I am writing to return. Would be great to get it out as string with c# code.

Comment: @Jon skeet.  SQL & SQL Azure still use TDS.

Comment: @tugberk: You shouldn't be basing your SQL on the underlying protocol. Use the SQL profiler to work out the cost of your queries, and make sure you return just the information you need.

Comment: @David: Thanks - I didn't want to sound overly confident with potentially out of date information :)

Comment: If you want to see the output from the query why not just execute the query in SQL Server Management Studio.  There you can even see the query plan as tugberk pointed out.